# request--curl-sync: Symbol’s value as variable is void: auto-revert-notify-watch-descriptor-hash-list

Tags: request

I switched to `Emacs 29.1` recently (from `Emacs 26`).

I had this working function:

```el
(require 'request)
(require 'json-mode)

(defun get-inspire-json-from-id (TYPE INSPIRE_ID)
  "It returns, from the website https://inspirehep.net/, a JSON object corresponding to the TYPE and INSPIRE_ID."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((RESULT nil))
      (request
       (url-encode-url (format "https://inspirehep.net/api/%s/%s" TYPE INSPIRE_ID))
       :headers '(("Accept" . "application/json"))
       :sync t
       :parser (cl-function
        (lambda ()
          (recode-region (point-min) (point-max) 'utf-8 'binary)
          (json-pretty-print-buffer)
          (setq RESULT (buffer-string))))
       :success (cl-function
         (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
           (insert data)))
       :error (cl-function
           (lambda (&key error-thrown &allow-other-keys)
         (message "Errore durante la richiesta: %S" error-thrown)
         (setq RESULT nil)))
       )

      ;; *Debug*
      ;; (write-file (format "/tmp/inspire-%s-json.json" TYPE) nil)
      RESULT)))
```

I called it this way:

```el
(get-inspire-json-from-id-debug "literature" "494058")
```

Now the function is broken and I get the error:

```
request--curl-sync: Symbol’s value as variable is void: auto-revert-notify-watch-descriptor-hash-list
```

I have not been able to locate the problem.
Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by updating `request` package:

```el
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-upgrade-all)
```